# Setting Cell Formats with xlwt format strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwt

I've looked around for several different xlwt formats for cells, but I can't find a comprehensive list.
Excel provides the following options for cell content formatting:
(general, number, currency, accounting, date, time, percentage, fraction, scientific, text, special, custom)
Obviously custom isn't what I want, but what are the formatting strings for all these different options? For example, I've seen:

```
date_format = XFStyle()
date_format.num_format_str = 'dd/mm/yyyy'

currency_format = XFStyle()
currency_format.num_format_str = '$#,##0.00'
```

Is there somewhere I can get a comprehensive list of those formatting strings? The documentation on http://www.python-excel.org/ doesn't have much, and the tutorial at the bottom only seems to have dates.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get Excel to dynamically show all the decimals in a float? The currency string suggests the number must match the number of zeros shown after the decimal point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found a list. I was just being stupid about looking for it.
The GitHub project has a list of number format strings here:
https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/num_formats.py

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import datetime
Time = datetime.datetime.now()
Currency = 234

#Format Date
style1 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style1.num_format_str = 'DD-MM-YY'

#Format Currency
style2 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style2.num_format_str = '$#,##0.00'

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')

worksheet.write(0, 1, Time, style1)
worksheet.write(0, 2, Currency, style2)
```